# Factory returns promise error "getToken undefined"

Tags: angularjs

I have got the following service:

```
app.factory('$FCMPlugin', $FCMPlugin);

        $FCMPlugin.$inject = [];

        function $FCMPlugin() {
            var service = {
                getToken: function() {
                        FCMPlugin.getToken();
                }
            };
            return service;            

          }
```

Then, when the user has logged in, I call the factory from my controller expecting a token value as return:

```
$FCMPlugin.getToken()
    .then(function(token){
        console.log(token);
        $scope.user.fcmToken = token;
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log('error');
    })
```

But I am getting that getToken is undefined... why could it be? Is it well defined?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Also I  have try with:

Factory.js

```
 function $FCMPlugin() {
            var service = {
                getToken: function() {
                        return FCMPlugin.getToken()
                            .then(function(token){
                                return token;
                            })
                            .catch(function(error){
                                throw error;
                            });
                }
            };
            return service;            

          }
```

Another try but still same error..

```
function $FCMPlugin() {
            var service = {
                getToken: function(success, fail) {
                        FCMPlugin.getToken(success, fail);

                }
            };
            return service;            

          }
```

Controller:

```
$FCMPlugin.getToken()
        .success(function(token){
            console.log(token);
            $scope.user.fcmToken = token;
        })
        .error(function(error){
            console.log('no error');
        })
```

Error: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined

I have tried every way but still nothing..

Comment: Try to pass success and fail inside getToken method like this:
getToken: function(success, fail) { FCMPlugin.getToken(success, fail) }

Comment: Hi Marko, do you have an example? How should I get the promise in controller?

Comment: inside app factory change this line: var service = {
                getToken: function(success, fail) {
                        FCMPlugin.getToken(success, fail);
                }
            };
Give a try.

Comment: didn't work.....

Comment: I found this example: https://gist.github.com/TmanTman/148f7902992682b4796b1e9cb9d75151
I really don't know what can be a problem. Good luck!

Comment: Also, try inside controller to use a callback instead promise.

Comment: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined

Comment: Did you installed the: cordova-plugin-fcm ?

Comment: Yes. The plugin is working just fine. The problem is about callback from service/factory.